# Centralizer and Normalizer of Matrix Polynomial

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to know what is the centralizer of $A=\mathbb{F}_p[M]$ and index of normalizer of $A^*$ if the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is not square, where $M$ is $2\times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is odd prime, $M$ is not a scalar matrix. For the first one it is clear $A$ is contained in the centralizer and my guess is the centralizer is $A$ itself. When I do calculation by taking arbitrary $M$ I was stucked since if \begin{align*}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
x&y\\ 
z&w
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and I take
\begin{align*}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\ 
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
in centralizer, I only got $bz=cy$ (since one only needs to check the commutativity with $M$). I checked my guess for \begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
and it is true. For the normalizer I have no idea at the moment.

Comment: The two answers to this question explain how to tackle this problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353023/counting-centralizers-of-a-matrix-over-a-finite-field-with-a-particular-minimal

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks!